# Why is there a difference between someone inheriting an animal and a Kohen receiving it from a Yisrael for the purposes of T'murah?

Tags: korban, maseches-temura

In T'murah 1:1, the Mishna starts off by saying:

> הכל ממירים, אחד אנשים ואחד נשים.
>
> The laws of T'murah apply to everyone, men and women.
>
> <sub>(my own loose translation)</sub>

The G'mara (2a-b) explains that the reason the word "הכל" ("everyone") is included is to include that if someone inherits an animal that has been designated as a *korban*, then T'murah applies to the inheritor; that is, if they try to move the designation to another animal, then both animals become designated as korbanot.

At the end of the Mishna, when Rabbi Yochanan and Rabbi Akiva are arguing about whether or not T'murah applies to the B'chor (firstborn animal, that a Yisrael gives to the Kohen), since the B'chor is given to the Kohen alive (unlike the Asham and Chatat, which the Kohen only receives the meat of), Rabbi Akiva says that it is designated in the "בית הבעלים" ("house of the owner"), and can only be made T'murah there as well.

Kehati says:

> **אף תמורה בבית הבעלים** — חלה בבית הבעלים של הקרבן, אבל אין היא חלה בבית הכהן. הלכך דווקא הבעלים ממירים בבכור, כל זמן שהוא ברשותם, הואיל וברשותם חלה הקדושה עליו, אבל הכהן, שקיבל בכור מישראל, אינו ממיר בו.

In essence, he explains that since the B'chor acquired the status of K'dusha while in the possession of the original owners, the Yisraelim, the Kohen who then receives it from them now does not have T'murah apply to if he tries to change the animal, because he wasn't the one to give the original status to the animal.

If that is the case, why then does the G'mara conclude that T'murah does apply to a case where someone *inherits* the animal that has been designated? In both cases the person currently in possession of the animal was not the one to have originally designated it; why, then, does T'murah apply to the inheritor but not the Kohen?

Comment: Not just Temura, but Semikha and Nechasim (Menachot 9:7). Seemingly inheritance doesn't count as external property transfer for these purposes.

Comment: The Gemorah gives the reason why a Yoresh can make a Temurah as being something we learn out from the extra word in the  Posuk of     דהמר ימיר  which includes him in the Parsha of Temurah. Otherwise, he indeed wouldn't be able to. There is no Posuk to include a Kohen in Temurah by Bechor.